# Run multiple spring boot app from one main spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have two spring boot projects configured to run on ports `8080` and `8081` individually, when they are run using the jar exec command.

I don't want to run them individually and want to serve them from same web server and on different contexts.

Like how I can drop the jar files into a `/webapp` folder of a `tomcat` installation and the server serves both projects from same webserver.

Can I create another `spring-boot` app running on port `8083`, which can run these two projects on different contexts in same app , by taking the jars of first two projects as maven dependencies.

If so how it can be done

Comment: Does [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) help?

Comment: If you want to achieve that you should build `.war` files instead of `.jar` files. [see this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy)

Comment: Yes @HopeyOne yes this would help. I can package them separately into war and drop into a tomcat. But i dont want to drop them into tomcat. I want to take two springboot jars into third sb project by taking them as a maven dependency and run the third one.